# Manipulate `Block` in pandoc lua filter

Tags: lua, pandoc

In a pandoc-filter, is it possible to change a `Block` object that I receive with

```lua
-- div.content is a list of Blocks, see [1]
local elem = table.remove(div.content, 1)
```

with `elem` being a `BlockQuote [Para [Str "Text"]]`  to something like `Para [Str "Text"]`? In short, remove the `Blockquote` object around the `Para`?

---

- [[1] Documentation of `div` in pandoc](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#type-div)

Comment: can you not access `elem.Para`?

Comment: I get a `nil` for this.

Comment: Only other thing I've seen would be `elem.c`. Seems to have a `t` and `c` property.
If that doesnt work, grab a recursive lua table dumping function from the net and run elem through it to see what it has inside.

Comment: I stumbled upon the [`walk`](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#type-block:walk) function, but I still wasn't able to retrieve the `Para`. I only get the `Str[ "Text"]` with it. Do you have any experience with this function?

Comment: No, but just read up a bit more and `elem.t` is the type name as a string e.g. `BlockQuote` and `elem.c` seems to be the content, so in the above case `elem.c[1]` should be the `Para` element. and `elem.c[1].c[1]` would be he `Str`.

Comment: It worked! Thank you! Would you like to add your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having had a search around the net, it seems from [Pandoc Lua Filters](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#creating-a-handout-from-a-paper), that the element has a property `t` that seems to stand for tag or type maybe and a property `c` standing for content, an array style table containing each child element.

So in this case `elem.c[1]` would be the first child element.

Answer (score 1):

With Lua i think `string.gsub()` is fine for search and replace all occurances that matching the pattern(s).
Also it is a string Method that can be chained.
So i think you will accomplish it with...

```
Lua 5.4.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2022 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> a_block = ('BlockQuote [Para [Str "Text"]]'):rep(10, '\n')
> a_block:gsub('%w+%s%[%f[P]', ''):gsub('%]%]',']')
Para [Str "Text"]
Para [Str "Text"]
Para [Str "Text"]
Para [Str "Text"]
Para [Str "Text"]
Para [Str "Text"]
Para [Str "Text"]
Para [Str "Text"]
Para [Str "Text"]
Para [Str "Text"]   10
```

This can be done on the fly...

```
local elem = table.remove(div.content, 1):gsub('%w+%s%[%f[P]', ''):gsub('%]%]',']')
```

( If `table.remove()` returns a string than it can be chained with its methods like `gsub()` )

Comment: thank you for your answer. I probably wasn't clear with my question. I changed it accordingly.

Comment: Thx for more Info - Answer extended.

Comment: Thanks again, with `strings` it solves the issue, however I am not handling strings in this case, I am handling pandoc `Block` objects. I edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The filter should operate on BlockQuotes, so it needs a global function with that name; only BlockQuote elements will be passed to that function. The function can return either a single Block, or a list of Blocks. The latter is the type of the `.content` property, so it all comes together as

```lua
function BlockQuote (bq)
  return bq.content
end
```

That function will unwrap the content of a BlockQuote, so `BlockQuote [Para [...]]` will become just `Para [...]`, as requested.